# Finding displacement from acceleration and time

Tags: acceleration, time, displacement

Can someone open my eyes my disproving the formula that I arrived. I understand it is wrong but where exactly is the mistake?
[image]

Comment: You have confused v = average velocity and v= final velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is defined as displacement per unit time. But when the motion is accelerated one then you can't directly apply

$displacement = (velocity )(time)$

The above formula is applicable only when the motion is uniform for the given time i.e. your velocity remains the same in that given time.

But for an accelerated motion ( i.e. velocity is not uniform )    the formula for displacement becomes

$s =ut + \frac{1}{2} at^2$ .

So using $s ={v}{t} $  or

$v=\frac{s}{t}$.
for an accelerated motion was your mistake.

Hope it helps .